# Adding "fixed" to my navbar makes it disappear

Tags: frontend, navbar, tailwind-css

When I add `fixed` to my Navbar component, it disappears. Here is my code (I use tailwindcss):

```
  return (
<div className='flex w-full justify-between items-center h-24 max-w-[1240px] mx-auto px-4 text-white z-10'>
  <h1 className='w-full text-3xl font-bold text-[#00df9a]'>PORTFOLIO.</h1>
  <ul className='hidden md:flex'>
      <li className='p-4'><Link to="hero" smooth={true} duration={500}>Home</Link></li>
```

Comment: It has a z-index of 10, so is it below something else now? It will be positioned by its containing block, is that `body` or something else? Can you see where it is using dev tools?

Comment: thanks for your answer, even with a 1000 index, she still not appear ..., its in the return section of a react component

Comment: When you inspect the full page output you will need to use dev tools to find it in the DOM. In my experience if it is not a z-index issue then it is either positioned out of the viewport or the width and/or height is zero so it can't be seen. Otherwise I really think we need to see a code example, It is too dependant on the containing block element.

Comment: Make sure the parent is relatively positioned

Comment: Hey i fixed it by adding "sticky top-0"

Comment: Then answer your own post for people with the same problem